# Which variables are set at the program execution in Python other than __name__?

Tags: python, variables, interpreter

I have read that some variables are set in Python at program execution (like `__name__`)? What are the variables that are set before the program is executed by the Python Interpreter other than `__name__`?

Comment: What do you mean by "before program execution"? ``__name__`` is set as part of [loading a module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.load_module), which is part of executing a program.

Comment: You have all the builtins. Try `dir(__builtins__)`. But I'm not completely sure of what you mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should answer your question:

```
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>>
```